# ASP.NET Core route form get URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have the following routes setup in startup..

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "areas",
    pattern: "{area=Admin}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

endpoints.MapControllerRoute("pagination",
    "Inventory/Page/{page}",
    new { area = "Admin", controller = "Inventory", action = "Index", page = 1 });
```

These work perfectly for URLs like:

```
/Admin/Inventory/Edit/6
/Inventory/Page/2
```

I have the following action methods defined in the `InventoryController`:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int page = 1)
{
    var pageInfo = new PagingInfo()
    {
        CurrentPage = page,
        ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
        TotalItem = await _inventoryRepository.CountAsync(new InventorySpecification())
    };

    var model = new InventoryListViewModel()
    {
        Inventories = await _inventoryRepository.GetAsync(new InventorySpecification(page, PageSize)),
        PagingInfo = pageInfo
    };

    return View(model);
}

[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Search(string filter, int page = 1)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
    {
        RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    var pageInfo = new PagingInfo()
    {
        CurrentPage = page,
        ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
        TotalItem = await _inventoryRepository.CountAsync(new InventorySpecification(filter))
    };

    var model = new InventoryListViewModel()
    {
        Inventories = await _inventoryRepository.GetAsync(new InventorySpecification(filter, page, PageSize)),
        PagingInfo = pageInfo
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

I have this view model class:

```
public class InventoryListViewModel : BaseListViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Inventory> Inventories { get; set; }
    public string SearchString { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following razor syntax in Index.cshtml

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <form asp-action="Search" method="get">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input asp-for="SearchString" type="text" class="form-control" name="filter" placeholder="Enter an inventory item">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Go!</button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When the user submits the form, I would like to see ....

```
/Inventory/Search/{filter}/Page/1
```

I have tried several routes in startup without any success.

Any ideas or suggestions would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: through the browser can you enter the url to check if it is accessible?

Comment: I am able to enter the URL and it works...

I have endpoints.MapControllerRoute(inventory",
                "Inventory/Search/{filter}/Page/{page}", new { area = "Admin", controller = "Inventory", action = "Search", filter="All", page=1});

 Problem is when I submit the form, I don't get the desired URL. I get..

/Inventory/Search/All/Page?filter=somevalue

Answer (score 0):

After a little more searching on SO, I stumbled upon this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846584/asp-net-mvc-force-style-of-get-url-on-form)...

I have this route in startup...

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute("inventory",
"Inventory/Search/{filter}/Page/{page}",
new { area = "Admin", controller = "Inventory", action = "Search", filter="All", page=1});
```

The following entry to my Inventory controller..

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SearchPost(string filter, int page=1)
{
   return await Task.Run<IActionResult>(() =>
   {
     return RedirectToAction(nameof(Search), new { filter = filter, page = page });
   });
}
    
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Search(string filter, int page)
{
   if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
   {
     RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
   }
    
   var pageInfo = new PagingInfo()
   {
      CurrentPage = page,
      ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
      TotalItem = await _inventoryRepository.CountAsync(new InventorySpecification(filter))
   };
    
   var model = new InventoryListViewModel()
   {
     Inventories = await _inventoryRepository.GetAsync(new InventorySpecification(filter, page, PageSize)),
     PagingInfo = pageInfo
     };
    
     return View(model);
}
```

and I made a simple adjustment to the form, making it a post vs get and referencing the SearchPost method.

```
  <form asp-action="SearchPost" method="post">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input asp-for="SearchString" type="text" class="form-control" id="filter" name="filter" placeholder="Enter a server name or instance name">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Go!</button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </form>
```